# Why did my dog just eat my cat?

Tags: nethack

I was carrying around a tripe ration in an effort to keep my dog close, when I found a nice housecat that was in need of a good home.

So I fed it my tripe ration, and a very happy heart appeared over its head.  I named him Katt, and he purred and snuggled against me because he was so happy to have a real home.

Then a few turns later, my dog **attacked and** ate him.  I don't know if it was sibling rivalry or not, but he just got angry at the cat and went to town.

Do pets not like each other, or was it something else?  Up until that point my dog had a nice and sunny disposition.

---

Aside from the bolded edit above, here are some more clarifications:

1. The dog had just killed and eaten a black naga hatchling
2. The cat was alive at the time, the dog simply started biting him.
3. I'm pretty low level still, I'm not wearing any jewelry of any kind.
4. The dog has eaten pretty well...I've been letting it take care of all lichens, jackals, etc so far.
5. Also no traps within the immediate area either.

Comment: @lilserf: i'm pretty sure ANY nethack question can be phrased into an amusing title

Comment: Are you playing somewhere that saves ttyrecs?

Comment: @Wooble: I'm playing the graphical client for Windows Mobile.  That character actually died recently and I doubt I have any record left.

Comment: It's a dog and it's a cat. Nature tells dogs to eat cats. Nuff said.

Comment: I'm sure you mean 'lycans' (werewolves) instead of 'lichens' (...  a composite organism consisting of a fungus and a photosynthetic partner growing together in a symbiotic relationship).

Comment: @NigelNquande: I'm sure I don't.

Comment: My mistake, then.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Under normal conditions pets won't attack other pets. However they have no problem eating a former pet's corpse. So one of the following things might have happened:

- Something else (a monster or a boulder trap for example) killed your cat and your dog ate the corpse.
- Your dog became confused from hunger, randomly attacked your cat and then ate it.
- You're wearing a ring of conflict which caused the dog to attack anything in its range including your cat.

Comment: The dog attacked the cat with no provocation that I could see....and the dog had just previously eaten a black naga hatchling, and I'm wearing no rings yet.  Would the hatchling have confused it?

Comment: @sepp2k: updated the question with some clarifications

Comment: @espais: Eating black naga corpses does not cause confusion. Did your dog fight an umber hulk recently or did it maybe get hit by a thrown potion of confusion? (I'm assuming that you neither attacked not cast a spell at it)

Comment: @sepp2k: No, really nothing eventful had happened that I noticed within probably 10-15 turns.  We had just descended some stairs and it went nuts a turn or two after we made it down.

Comment: Are you sure the cat was still tame?

Comment: @Wooble: it still had a heart over its head...

Comment: i think i'll have to go with this answer because it makes the most sense...i must have missed a status message at some point

Comment: Are you sure the *dog* was still tame?