# Can Vegans eat Jewelry?

Tags: nethack

I am a [Vegan](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Vegan#Vegan). Would it break the conduct if I [eat jewelry](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Eating_jewelry)?

The Vegan conduct states that I can eat:

> - food rations, cram rations, K-rations, C-rations and lembas wafers
> - melons, oranges, carrots, pears, apples, bananas, kelp, eucalyptus, garlic, wolfsbane,  and user-defined fruit
> - the corpse of any monster (or a tin of its 'meat') represented by `b`, `j`, or `F`.
> - tins of spinach

There is no mention of metal/wood. Additionally, the pages on eating jewelry, [amulets](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Amulet), and [rings](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Rings) don't say anything about the Vegan conduct.

Comment: ...and [once](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147329/can-monsters-hallucinate) [again](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/why-did-my-dog-just-eat-my-cat), [another](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159144/how-can-i-kill-puppies-without-consequences) [NetHack](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159747/why-do-i-stop-eating-corpses-should-i-keep-eating-them-anyway) hits the Hot Questions list. ;-)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen What did you expect?  This is a timeless question of great implication, Nethack or otherwise! How long have my Vegan friends have wondered if they can gobble down a spare ring as a midnight snack! Well, no longer shall they deliberate! For this website will settle this issue once and for all.

Comment: Depends: is the jewelry bacon-flavored?

Comment: The page you link to has been updated - "Additionally, vegans may eat jewelry"

Comment: @OrangeDog take a look who edited it: http://nethackwiki.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Conduct&action=history

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vegans can indeed eat jewelry. From the [guidebook](http://www.nethack.org/v343/Guidebook.html):

> A strict vegan diet is one which avoids any food derived from animals.
>   The primary source of nutrition is fruits and vegetables. The corpses
>   and tins of blobs (`b'), jellies (`j'), and fungi (`F') are also
>   considered to be vegetable matter. Certain human food is prepared
>   without animal products; namely, lembas wafers, cram rations, food
>   rations (gunyoki), K-rations, and C-rations. Metal or another normally
>   indigestible material eaten while polymorphed into a creature that can
>   digest it is also considered vegan food. Note however that eating such
>   items still counts against foodless conduct.

Specifically:

> Metal or another normally indigestible material eaten while polymorphed into a creature that can digest it is also considered vegan food.

So if you are a [gelatinous cube](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gelatinous_cube), go ahead and slurp down those wooden rings. If you are a [rust monster](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Rust_monster), [rock mole](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Rock_mole), or [xorn](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Xorn), [crunch](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/You_hear_a_crunching_noise.#Messages) away at your metallic amulets and rings.